# Why do userinput shows as "undefined"?

Tags: javascript, html

**Problem solved in the comments.Thanks everybody!**

I only start to learn JavaScript and begin to figure out how DOM works.But when I try to append userinput(stored in the var) value to the end of the list,I get "undefined",although everything works with  the text.

As I understand,it means that there is no value stored in the variable,but the author,which JS course I am currently watching,has almost the same code,but everything works.I tried to redefine the Id/class names for the variables,test with the string instead of the variable(everything is working) and make the code identical to the author,but it still gives me the same error.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var modify_list = document.getElementsByClassName("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
 console.log(modify_list.value);
 var li = document.createElement("li");
 li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(modify_list.value));
 ul.appendChild(li);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>DOM</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>What plans do I have till the end of the summer?</h1>
  <p>They are:</p>
  <input type="text" name="add activities" class="userinput" placeholder="add activities">
  <button id="button">Send</button>
  <ul>
   <li>Learn German</li>
   <li>Learn Japanese</li>
   <li>Learn Java Script</li>
   <li>Physical activities</li>
  </ul>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("userinput")[0].value will do the thing..

Comment: @Quentin, thanks for help,I found the problem.Didn't find the post when looking.Can be closed now.

Comment: @J D Thank you,it's because Classes are plurals and we must define it's the first element,right?

Comment: Yes it returns array so you have to iterate..

Comment: @EndOfTheGlory — It was closed before you made that comment. If you want to delete it, then you have to do that yourself.

Comment: Modify this line

var modify_list = document.getElementsByClassName("userinput")[0];